# Mathematical Induction Basis Step Not Equal

Tags: proof-verification, induction

I am to prove the following statement using mathematical induction for all positive integers:
$$
1 - 2 + 2^2 - 2^3 +\dots+(-1)^n  2^n = 
\frac{2^n\cdot2^1\cdot(-1)^n+1}{3}.
$$
However, for the basis step, I am getting $-2$ for the left side and $-1$ for the right side, which are obviously not equal. The assignment indicates that the statement is true though, so I am missing something or could this be a typo in the statement?

Comment: Your base step is n=0.  That should get you 1 on both sides.

Comment: You are getting $-2$ on the left-hand side?  If $n=0, 1\ne-2$, if $n=1, 1-2 \ne -2$  Not sure how you are getting anything but an odd number on the left hand side.

Comment: @lordoftheshadows My instructor mentioned that the basis step assumes $n=1$. Can the basis step also be $n=0$? Wouldn't there be a problem regardless because both sides of the equation are not equal when $n=1$?

Comment: I think there's some confusion about how we do induction.  For these types of problems we're trying to prove P(x)->P(x+1).  The basis step is just the lowest x such that P(x) is true for all greater x.  The basis step depends on the problem.  Also they are equivilent for n=1.  They're both -1.  Make sure you're finding the sum on the right hand side.

Comment: **When $n=1$, both sides are equal to $-1$** hence there is nothing bizarre with this case, and one can indeed choose it as "the base step". (This was already mentioned, basically, but with no apparent effect on the OP.) And one could also use the case $n=0$ since then both sides are $+1$...

Answer (score 1):

For $n=1$, you have to stop at the exponent $1$, so the left hand side is
$$
1+(-1)^1\cdot2^1
$$
and the right hand side is
$$
\frac{2\cdot 2\cdot(-1)+1}{3}=\frac{-4+1}{3}
$$
and both equal $-1$.

Whether you start at $1$ or at $0$ depends on your site's conventions or on the particular assignment. The formula also holds for $n=0$, when the left hand side is $1$ and the right hand side is
$$
\frac{2^0\cdot2\cdot(-1)^0+1}{3}=\frac{2+1}{3}=1
$$